# How to refer to UTF-16 character in C?

Tags: c, utf-16

Now I'm writing a C .header file for my library, which handles `UTF-16` characters.

This .h should compile on `Linux/Windows 32/64 bits` in `MSVC/GCC`.
Since it's a lib header, I cannot stick to `C99` and later. So I cannot use `wchar_t` or `uint16_t`. How can I specify a `UTF-16` variable?

So far I came to this:

```
#if _WIN32 
  typedef wchar_t char_UTF16;
#else 
  #if __GNUC__
    typedef unsigned short char_UTF16;
  #else
    #error "Compiler not supported"
  #endif
#endif
```

But I really don't think this is the best solution.

Comment: It is not very clear what your objection is based on.  The coding element in utf-16 takes 16 bits so unsigned short will work fine on both.  Using wchar_t in win32 is fine as well, tends to make a debugger smarter.  Just keep in mind that it is a variable-length encoding, a codepoint takes either 1 or 2 elements.

Comment: Alternatively, use `wchar_t` on windows and `unsigned short` everywhere else.  It *might* work on the unsupported compiler ...  (But this is the best basic approach).

Comment: What reason is there to be, today, writing a library that does **not** feel at liberty to **demand** its clients to be only using compilers compliant to a standard released 17 years ago?

Comment: 1. Because it's not a standard 2. As you've noted yourself unsigned short is a not a good alternative to character types, but the only one I came across.

Comment: @DevSolar A commercial reason :)

Comment: @user2854853: One of my projects is a *standard* C library. (You know, `<string.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, all the nice stuff.) I couldn't give a {bleep}'s {bleeep} {bleeeeeeeeeeeeeep} for pre-C99 compilers. I'm rapidly losing patience with environments where C++**11** is ruled out...

Comment: "*Because it's not a standard*" -- What isn't a standard? C99 certainly is, though it's been officially superseded by C11.

Comment: @DevSolar Unfortunately we all know that C11 compiler != C11 project...

Comment: @user2854853: C doesn't really have "character types" anyway; they're really just integer types. It should also be noted that the C headers for Microsoft's C runtime library define `wchar_t` as an `unsigned short` (except when compiling in C++ mode), so I don't see the objection in you defining your `char_UTF16` as an `unsigned short` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try some of the builtin types in a compiler-agnostic way:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#if (WCHAR_MAX==65535) && WCHAR_MIN==0
typedef wchar_t char_UTF16;
#elif USHRT_MAX==65535
typedef unsigned short char_UTF16;
#elif UINT_MAX==65535
typedef unsigned char_UTF16;
#else
#    error "Cannot find 16-bit type"
#endif
```

(there's no point in trying `unsigned long`, since the standard requires it to be at least 32 bit wide)

... although, I'm not really sure if you should even try `wchar_t`, probably I'd go straight for the numeric types, otherwise you risk having your clients assuming that e.g. wide char literals are of the "right" type for your library while in facts they are only on Windows.

Comment: Your thoughts on `char16_t` (which is at least 16-bit and works with `__STDC_UTF_16__` and character constants like `u'A'`)?

Comment: Hmmm,  did not see that prohibition against `char16_t`.  IAC, trying to work with best available types and then down-grading to less and less desirable choices is the best approach.

Comment: BTW Do not think `#elif UINT_MAX==65535` is possible after `#elif USHRT_MAX==65535`.  Suggest re-ordering: `#elif UINT_MAX==65535` _then_ `#elif USHRT_MAX==65535`.